# Not able to remotely access MySQL on GCP VM

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench

I am having problem to connect to MariaDB on Linuc GCP VM. I have followed all practices to expose the VM on 3306, I use ephemeral IP. The VM is reachable as I have nginx installed. I have create remote user in MySQL, enabled remote access but still nothing. When i cannoct from my PC with MySQL Workbench i get connection error. What can it be?

I have also followed this:
[enter link description here](https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/how-enable-remote-access-your-mariadbmysql-database)

Update

this the output of netstat:

`$> netstat -ant | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Result of nmap is more intersting though:

```
PORT STATE SERVICE 
22/tcp open ssh 
80/tcp open http 
443/tcp closed https 
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
```

I do not see 3306 but it is a port I have opened on firewall rule in GCP... How can it be is not shown?

Comment: Accordingly to the [documentation](https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/how-enable-remote-access-your-mariadbmysql-database) "By default, the MariaDB server is listening on localhost only for security reasons. You can check it with the following command: `netstat -ant | grep 3306` ". **1**. Have you changed configuration of MariaDB to make it able to listen at the internal IP of your VM? **2**. Please update your question with output of the command : `netstat -ant | grep 3306`.

Comment: done. pls check. I do have [mysqld]
bind_address=0.0.0.0 in the my.cnf config file.

Comment: Thanks! Have you checked open ports with `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOR_VM`? Also, I think you should try to [remove](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) `bind-address` directive and check connection again

Comment: I removed the bind_address from my.cnf but same negative result. Result of nmap is more intersting though: PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
 I do not see 3306 but it is a port I have opened on firewall rule in GCP... How can it be is not shown?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found a mistake. It was in the GCP firewall configuration rule. The tag name of the VM was spelled wrongly. thanks.